# How to get guard address inside genosis safe app?

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-apps-sdk, safe-core

I am using safe react template [link]: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-apps-sdk/tree/master/packages/cra-template-safe-app. I have a requirement where i need to get the transaction guard contract address associated with that safe inisde the safe app. How to get it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `getStorageAt` from the [StorageAccessible](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/761f6782b327493bc9869b0754471824e2a6635f/contracts/common/StorageAccessible.sol#L13) contract to get the guard address from the Safe's internal storage.

The guard address is [stored at slot](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/761f6782b327493bc9869b0754471824e2a6635f/contracts/base/GuardManager.sol#L39) `0x4a204f620c8c5ccdca3fd54d003badd85ba500436a431f0cbda4f558c93c34c8`

Comment: Can you please guide how to get it inside the react app? Its a Safe Contract internal function.

Comment: If you check GenosisSafel2 Contract, [link](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x3e5c63644e683549055b9be8653de26e0b4cd36e#writeContract) we don't have any function to get the guard address. @mikheevm

Comment: My bad, haven't spotted that the method was internal, I've just updated my answer

Comment: What should be the input of the parameters of offset and length? @mikheevm