# UUPS upgradable Transaction Guard smart contract not working with Genosis Safe

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis, safe-core-sdk

I have written a Transaction Guard smart contract [What is Transaction Guard](https://help.safe.global/en/articles/5324092-what-is-a-transaction-guard#:%7E:text=The%20Gnosis%20Safe%20is%20a,out%2Dof%2D%20m%20schemes.)  which is upgradable (UUPS method openzappelin [What is upgradable contracts](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/proxies)). So when we deploy this Transaction Guard Smart contract, it basically gives a proxy address. When i set it as Guard by using **setGuard** method of Genosis Safe, the restriction which i gave in **checkTransaction** function of Transaction Guard [Example of Transaction Guard Contract](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/examples/guards/OnlyOwnersGuard.sol) doesn't seems to be working at all. Is it like proxy contract cannot work as a transaction guard in Genosis safe?
When i set the guard to the  Transaction Guard smart contract (without UUPS Upgradability feature), it works exactly the way it should be.

Comment: It there a chance you might share some code, I would like to see how you implemented the contract. A lot can go wrong here. So it's hard to tell what might be the core issue.

Comment: @Sky Just consider this example [Link](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/examples/guards/OnlyOwnersGuard.sol) .
At line 49,  inside the if condition, let say i am checking msgSender with some specific signatory public key(Hardcoded) and if it doesnt match, reverting the transaction. For Upgradability, i am followin [Tutorial](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-uups-proxy-pattern-upgrade-smart-contracts/).
1 important thing, i am using factory cloning method to create this Transaction Guard contract [Tutorial](https://github.com/optionality/clone-factory)

Comment: So let me understand this. The Transaction Guard contract/logic works on its own. But once you made it upgradable, it stopped working. Right?

Comment: @Sky No. I just tested it. Its working fine. I think the issue is because i am using factory cloning method.[Link](https://github.com/optionality/clone-factory) Inside createThing function,  Thing(clone).init(_name, _value) basically use to initialise variable.  Now in UUPS also, we have some specific ways to initialise constructor. And i am using the clone factory init method to initialise some variable as required in my use case. Is that the case?

Comment: @sky Lets say i have upgradable contract and i am directly using it as guard, it works fine. I have non upgradable contract and i am using it with Factory cloning method to create a clone first and then use it as transaction guard contract, then also its working fine. BUT if i  combine factory clone + upgradable then its failing somewhere.

Comment: So the issue has to be that something is getting initialized in your logic contract instead of your proxy. Cloning might be the reason for it, but it's hard to guess without being invested in your codebase.

Comment: @Sky can you please answer this question also [Link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/144762/how-to-get-guard-address-inside-genosis-safe-app)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I have an **Idea** of where the issue might be.

Your contract is inheriting `getOwners()` from `Safe.sol`
https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/Safe.sol

Which in turn inherits that function from `OwnerManager.sol`
https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/base/OwnerManager.sol

However, **none** of those contracts is upgradable, nor were they designed for such implementation.
Meaning that when you deploy them, the owner/owners are initialized in the storage of the `Logic contract`, not the `Proxy contract`.

This is why "for example" you will not use `Ownable.sol` when implementing UUPS, but you will use `OwnableUpgradable.sol` instead.

Please try to use some helper function to get/read the `owner()` address.
If they are all zero addresses, that is likely the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Bonus Note:**

I believe this function can be implemented in a more optimal way:

Instead of this:

```
    interface ISafe {
        function getOwners() external view returns (address[] memory);
    }
    /**
     * @notice Called by the Safe contract before a transaction is executed.
     * @dev Reverts if the transaction is not executed by an owner.
     * @param msgSender Executor of the transaction.
     */
    function checkTransaction(
        address,
        uint256,
        bytes memory,
        Enum.Operation,
        uint256,
        uint256,
        uint256,
        address,
        // solhint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
        address payable,
        bytes memory,
        address msgSender
    ) external view override {
        // Only owners can exec
        address[] memory owners = ISafe(msg.sender).getOwners();
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < owners.length; i++) {
            if (owners[i] == msgSender) {
                return;
            }
        }
    
        // msg sender is not an owner
        revert("msg sender is not allowed to exec");
    }
```

You might use this:

```
interface ISafe {
     function isOwner(address owner) external view returns (bool)
  }

/**
 * @notice Called by the Safe contract before a transaction is executed.
 * @dev Reverts if the transaction is not executed by an owner.
 * @param msgSender Executor of the transaction.
 */
function checkTransaction(
    address,
    uint256,
    bytes memory,
    Enum.Operation,
    uint256,
    uint256,
    uint256,
    address,
    // solhint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    address payable,
    bytes memory,
    address msgSender
) external view override {
    // Only owners can exec
    require(ISafe(msg.sender).isOwner(msgSender), "msg sender is not allowed to exec");
}
```

Didn't have time to test or think about this in detail, but it seemed like a plausible logic.